# Rearranging R Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

So I got this dataframe here:

```
> head(HR_df)
  Var1             Var2         Freq
1    A 2432.41955446887 0.0003224956
2    B 2432.41955446887 0.0004902131
3    C 2432.41955446887 0.0002273111
4    D 2432.41955446887 0.0001346622
5    E 2432.41955446887 0.0003125771
6    F 2432.41955446887 0.0004718690
```

I was trying to make the Var2 column values become all the column names, the Var1 become the row names and the Freq the value. Something like this:

```
> head(HR_df)
               2432        2501       ....
    A     0.0003224956  0.0004956001  ....
    B     .......         ......      ....
```

This was supposed to be a simple task, but I'm not very used to R and I can't find an answer anywhere.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
reshape(df,direction = "wide",idvar = "Var1",timevar = "Var2")
```

---

**Example**

Given dummy data

```
df <- structure(list(Var1 = c("A", "B", "C"), Var2 = c(0.0286285823676735, 
0.720798232126981, 0.206408529775217), Freq = c(0.166666666666667,
0.333333333333333, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

we will get

```
> reshape(df,direction = "wide",idvar = "Var1",timevar = "Var2")
  Var1 Freq.0.0286285823676735 Freq.0.720798232126981 Freq.0.206408529775217
1    A               0.1666667                     NA                     NA
2    B                      NA              0.3333333                     NA
3    C                      NA                     NA                    0.5                  0.5
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, it worked perfectly! ... just one more question, how can I eliminate that Freq in the column name?

Comment: @LucasLazari be advised that olumn names are not supposed to be numeric-only or have numeric leading character.